# Table design for multiple time series data

Tags: database-design, time-series

I have more than 200 separate time series data(each represent one variable) that I gather from different sources/REST API calls.

The frequency of each variable is different. Example temperature data is coming at very high frequency, but status data is very less frequent.

I am looking for suggestions for scalable table design to store these data. If I store all the data in one table with timestamp being the key, I think the table will have so much nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, my first thought is something like this:

```
Create Table Data_Type
(
    ID Int Identity
    , Data_Type_Description VarChar(100)
)

Create Table Data_Values
(
    ID Int Identity
    , Data_Value_Time_Stamp TimeStamp
    , Data_Type_ID Int       -- foreign key to Data_Type
    , Value Numeric(17, 4)   -- I'm guessing here
)
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, this is a good approach. It had crossed my mind, only one concern is that each time series value is of different data type. I have to store them as string and do the data type casting when I query it.