# Best performance design with time-series in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, time-series

(TL;DR)
The problem to solve with the design:
fast retrieval of related time-series with different frequency.
The tool:
A sql server table and index design.

The longer version:
I wish to calculate different functions at one or mere specific times or intervals with input data from time-series with different resolutions. And my intuition tells me that I need to think extra about the table/index design, given that the object is to have a fast join of the rows.

The designs advice I have seen so far is mostly concerned with retrieving a single time-series vs the problem  a hand here, retrieve values from different time-series at the same point of time. [Table design for multiple time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587600/table-design-for-multiple-time-series-data)

My purposed overall design, is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[time_series_definition](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [data_type_description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [duration_sec] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_time_series_definition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[time_series](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [start_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [end_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [time_series_definition_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [source] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [update_time] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_time_series] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[time_series]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_time_series_time_series_definition] FOREIGN KEY([time_series_definition_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[time_series_definition] ([ID])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data_values](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date_time] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [time_series_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [decimal](19, 8) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_data_values] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[data_values]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_data_values_time_series] FOREIGN KEY([time_series_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[time_series] ([ID])
```

The values [start_date], [end_date] are redundant, but believe that the might improve query speed, when the start/end of the series is know prior to lookup in the [data_values] table.

The [duration_sec] is to save space in [data_values] table since the series are evenly space within a specific series.

So given this design what is the best index/partition strategy to enable fast lookup of different series at a given time or time-interval.

Comment: This is all over the place. And there just isn't a right or wrong answer here. You have vaguely asked for other to design your database with almost no information. My guess is you are overthinking this. You should design your database to store the data for the situation. Then you start to concern yourself with the reporting requirements and deal with performance issues when they arise. If you have well designed database from the beginning the performance of the output is usually pretty straight forward.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange 
Thanks for your reply, and yes you are right. My problem is that asking for the best index strategy is dependent on the initial design. And I did consider framing the question as which index design is the best given my purposed design, but chose the very open question, in the hope that some designs the would perform better on time-series would might surface. Will add my initial design to the question.

Comment: Indexing is about 60% technical knowledge and 40% artisanship. There isn't really a best indexing strategy based on the table design. The table design certainly is part of it but the queries are crucial as well. What columns are used in where clauses? Is the identity really the best clustering index? How many rows are you anticipating in these tables? How many rows being returned by common queries. All of these are factors in an indexing strategy. I would build your system and deal with indexing when it becomes an issue.